# Django: How to implement custom authentification with master password

Tags: python, django, authentication

I need to implement a cusotm authorization in django which works like that:
A user logs in with his forname, surname and a global password which is stored in a specific table.

I am wondering what steos are neccessary to achieve this.

Things that came to my mind:

- custom user model
- custom authentification backend
- ???

The admin login should work as well.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom backend. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

There is a sample backend for static username/password in documentation. You can simply add firstname/lastname check in this function.